# Elasticsearch Errors while doing any operation with system?

Tags: python, ubuntu, elasticsearch, kibana

I have installed Elasticsearch and now due to some changes done by other folks at my work place some errors keep on popping up during any operation like update, install a new package and also the elasticsearch is not working properly.

**Error Log is attached for installing new package.**

```
$ sudo apt-get install bash-completion

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
bash-completion is already the newest version (1:2.1-4.2ubuntu1.1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 15 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Setting up elasticsearch (5.5.0) ...
Failed to restart systemd-sysctl.service: No such method 'RestartUnit'
See system logs and 'systemctl status systemd-sysctl.service' for details.
dpkg: error processing package elasticsearch (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 elasticsearch
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I even tried different solutions from online like trying to remove elasticsearch completely from system.

Steps I followed.

sudo rm -rf /var/lib/elasticsearch
sudo rm -rf /etc/elasticsearch
sudo apt-get install -f

```
$ sudo apt-get install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 15 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up elasticsearch (5.5.0) ...
Failed to restart systemd-sysctl.service: No such method 'RestartUnit'
See system logs and 'systemctl status systemd-sysctl.service' for details.
dpkg: error processing package elasticsearch (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 elasticsearch
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

sudo apt-get --purge autoremove elasticsearch

```
$ sudo apt-get --purge autoremove elasticsearch
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  elasticsearch*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 15 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 37.3 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
(Reading database ... 329402 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing elasticsearch (5.5.0) ...
Stopping elasticsearch service...Failed to stop elasticsearch.service: Unknown unit: elasticsearch.service
See system logs and 'systemctl status elasticsearch.service' for details.
Failed to get load state of elasticsearch.service: No such property 'LoadState'
dpkg: error processing package elasticsearch (--purge):
 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
Failed to restart systemd-sysctl.service: No such method 'RestartUnit'
See system logs and 'systemctl status systemd-sysctl.service' for details.
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 elasticsearch
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I restarted the system but the error keep on appearing again and again.

Any one with suggestions on how to solve this issue?

Also this command gives nothing

```
$ systemctl status systemd-sysctl.service
Failed to get properties: No such interface ''
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

is systemd your init service in this installation? Also what linux distribution is this? Which version of your distribution? I am currently thinking that you might not be using systemd, but the elasticsearch package is assuming this somehow.

I'd highly appreciate if you open up a bug report in the [elasticsearch repository](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues) with all of the above information, this warrants more research on the ES side (disclaimer: I'm an ES developer and keen to get this fixed :-).

Also: You can try to remove the `elasticsearch` package completely by running `dpkg -P elasticsearch`.

And in addition you can try to add `set -x` to `/var/lib/dpkg/info/elasticsearch.postinst` and run `sh /var/lib/dpkg/info/elasticsearch.postinst configure`
 to get more debugging output

Answer (score 2):

I had quite the same problem. 
It is obiviously related to systemctl, not elasticsearch.
First you have to determine if u are using it.

```
[[ `systemctl` =~ -\.mount ]] && echo yes || echo no
```

In my case, the answer was "no"

So you have to enable it.

Comment: The best tutorial to install elastic for me is this https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/how-to-install-elastic-stack-on-ubuntu-16-04/